# ASP.Net Generated SWF object

Tags: asp.net, flash

I'm working with SWF files (a video player that connects to Flash Media Server) and we're using ASP.Net. ASP.Net connects to the database and gets the stream URL, In the codebehind page, we get the InnerHTML value of the DIV of the video player and put the stream name in it.

Now it works perfectly, at least on Chrome, FireFox and Opera. However, in IE, it says that the movie, pertaining to the video player, is not loaded.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the stuf outside the embed tag.